# Wrong/Differente background image size on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a small website and since I'm almost done with it, I wanted to see it online... Everything went fine, from my laptop, on all screens the website was working great and the background image had the right size/position. I was too happy for that but once I opened it from my phone I got a surprise: the background-image looks totally different compared to the simulation performed from my laptop.

I already tried to add the below code but it did not change anything.
CSS:
.main-cont{background:
linear-gradient(
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)
),
url("../images/home-background.jpg")}}");

```
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        min-height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
  }
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-cont {
      background-attachment: scroll!important;
      height:100vh!important;
  }
}

  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  {{ flask_util_js.js }}
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/CSS/style.css') }}">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body >
  

<div class='main-cont' >

# Nav and main content

</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate your help, I'm completely stuck!

Link: http://alessio98.pythonanywhere.com/home/

[On mobile ( wrong )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOTh.jpg)
[On desktop ( correct )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swgh7.png)

Category section:

[Mobile simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNwcj.png)
[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHpjo.jpg)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot and/or a link so others can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Totally forgot about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link and screenshots, that helps a lot.

I believe the issue is `background-attachment` on the `div.main-cont` HTML element is not supported on the phone you have. In your browser, if you open the inspector and disable (uncheck) the CSS that says `background-attachment: fixed;`, you will get what you're seeing on your phone.

If you look at the browser support for `background-attachment` on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment%20fixed), it's only 82% overall, and no support at all on Safari. When that CSS doesn't work, instead of the background image getting sized for your screen, it instead gets sized for the `div` it's in, which is like the height of the page. That's why the image looks zoomed in/huge.

If you want to keep the `background-attachment: fixed` line, I'd recommend changing `background-position` to `top` and adding a new line `background-size: auto 100vh` to keep the size in check. It won't scroll on Safari, but it'll look more normal.

If you still want this background image to scroll with you, you'll probably have to change tactics and add an HTML element with `position: fixed` that has the background. Fixed images or content can get messy fyi.

Comment: Adding background-position: top and background-size:auto 100vh it helped only to resize the image but it doesn't scroll with the page on mobile devices, you can check the link again from your phone to see the result. After the image I have only white space. Additionally I changed the category section with a different layout and now neither the paragraph is displayed from my mobile device... I'll update my post adding this issue too.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that `background-attachment: fixed` is not a well-supported property and that making those changes was to fix the sizing, not the scrolling. As for the second issue, that would belong in a separate StackOverflow question.